# nginx with sub-request redirection removes query params

Tags: nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a test application which I am authorizing by having an internal `/auth` sub-request to flask back-end.

Authorization happens by **google sign in** and once authorized it comes back to redirect to the actual application client has asked for.

Although, I am facing an issue here. If the client has passed multiple query-parameters in the original URL, that is being stripped off afterwards.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1/test/?query1=val1&query2=val2&query3=val3
```

becomes

```
127.0.0.1/test/?query1=val1
```

Basically `$request_uri` does not hold all the query-parameters passed initially. URL Encoding is the culprit here?

Below is my Nginx configuration file.

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;
error_log stderr debug;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  _;

    proxy_set_header Host $host:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010/;
    }

    # Internal auth check endpoint.
    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010/auth;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }

    location ^~ /test/ {
        # Internal sub-request auth check before serving the endpoint.
        auth_request /auth;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8011/;

        # Redirect to @login if 401 from /auth.
        error_page 401 @login;
    }

    # Catch if 401/unauthorized and redirect for login
    location @login {
        return 302 /authorize?next=$request_uri;
    }
}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Just a workaround guess: Try `set $my_request_uri $request_uri;` before to encode it (again?) and then use `$my_request_uri`? Or try `$my_path$is_args$my_args` instead (you have to take care of `$my_path` with a regex and `$my_args` with the "set workaround" at the beginning of my comment via `$args`)? Or try `$uri` instead of `$request_uri`?

Comment: hey thanks for your comment. I have tried that before but did not work. The problem is when there is 401 returned from /auth and it goes to @login, it forgets the queryparams. 
Can I encode my query params like replacing '?' and '&' and '=' in the url in nginx?? That will definitely resolve my problem. 
I don't know how to do it in nginx. Please help.

Comment: @qräbnö ?? any update ?

Comment: Nginx does not let you encode stuff - you would have to use a scripting language (e.g. NJS for Javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally A solution of my own after 2 days of research into nginx. :D

As I was passing every incoming request to `/auth`, I encoded the url in the auth backend (Flask application in my case).
Sending back the encoded url to nginx by updating the headers like this.

```
@app.route('/auth')
def auth():
    if not has_valid_cookies():
        resp = flask.Response("", status=401)
        resp.headers['X-Original-URI'] = url_parse.quote(
            flask.request.headers.get('X-Original-URI', '/')
        )
        return resp
    else:
        return flask.jsonify(success=True)
```

The nginx conf becomes like below where I am sending `X-Original-URI` with original request_uri value back to backend, encode it there and hold the encoded value like this:

`auth_request_set $next_uri $upstream_http_X_Original_URI;`

`$next_uri` holds the encoded original request url.

```
    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010/auth;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }

    location ^~ /test/ {
        # Internal sub-request auth check before serving the endpoint.
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $next_uri $upstream_http_X_Original_URI;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8011/;

        # Redirect to @login if 401 from /auth.
        error_page 401 @login;
    }

    # Catch if 401/unauthorized and redirect for login
    location @login {
        return 302 /authorize?next=$next_uri;
    }
```